# Equality of triangle inequality in complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, triangles, absolute-value

$z$ and $w$ be nonzero complex numbers. How do I show that $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ if and only if $z=sw$ for some real positive number $s$.

I approached this by letting $z=a+ib$, and $w=c+id$, and kinda play around with it. I also tried to square both sides when proving forward direction, but I could not get it to work. Can anyone get me some ideas, maybe?

Thank you!

Comment: $z=sw$? what's $s$?

Comment: Squaring is not a bad idea. How did you prove the triangle inequality? Looking at that proof, a condition for equality should offer itself.

Comment: @Alex: oops, I forgot, real positive number :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First try to prove it in one direction.

Let $z = a + bi$ and $w = sa + sbi$. Then we have:

$$\mid z + w \mid = \mid a + bi + sa + sbi \mid = \mid |a(1+s) + (1+s)bi\mid = \sqrt{(1+s)^2a^2 + (1+s)^2b^2} = (1+s)\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + \sqrt{s^2a^2 + s^2b^2} = \mid z \mid + \mid w \mid$$

Now for the other direction. Let $z=a + bi$ and $w = c + di$. Then we have:

$$\mid z + w \mid =  \mid a + bi + c + di \mid = \mid (a+c) + (b+d)i \mid = \sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2}$$

$$\mid z \mid + \mid w \mid = \mid a + bi \mid + \mid c + di \mid = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}$$

Now since $\mid z + w \mid = \mid z \mid + \mid w \mid$ we have:

$$\sqrt{a^2 + c^2 + 2ac + b^2 + d^2 + 2bd} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}$$

Square both sides and we have:

$$a^2 + c^2 + 2ac + b^2 + d^2 + 2bd = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)}$$

$$ac + bd = \sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)}$$

Now square again and multiply out:

$$a^2c^2 + b^2d^2 + 2abcd = a^2c^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2d^2 + b^2d^2$$
$$2abcd = b^2c^2 + a^2d^2$$
$$b^2c^2 + a^2d^2 - 2abcd = 0$$
$$(cb - ad)^2 = 0 \implies cb = ad$$

So let $c = sa$, then we have:

$$scb = sad \implies sb = d$$

Hence $z = a + bi$ and $w = c + di = as + sbi$. Q.E.D.

Comment: I'm still working on it, thank you though!

Comment: I think I got it!

Comment: @Akaichan I've posted a solution for the other direction too. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I got to the $cb=ad$ part, and was stuck for a bit.

Comment: Why does your $s$ near the end have to be positive?

Comment: @Favst If $s<0$ then we have that $ac <0$ and similarly $bd<0$. This is impossible as $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)} = ac+bd < 0$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Why is it legit to suppose $c=sa$? Shouldn't it be deduced somehow from $bc=ad$ without supposing anything? I feel like in the proof, $A\implies B$, you are starting with $A$ is true, but in the process, you suppose that part of $B$ is also true. It feels like cheating.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a cleaner proof of the second direction, which avoids coordinates.

Suppose $|z + w| = |z| + |w|$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
|z|^2 + 2|zw| + |w|^2
&= (|z| + |w|)^2 \\
&= |z + w|^2 \\
&= (z + w)(\overline{z + w}) \\
&= z\overline{z} + z\overline{w} + w\overline{z} + w\overline{w} \\
&= |z|^2 + 2\mathrm{Re}(z\overline{w}) + |w|^2.
\end{align*}
$$
This implies $|zw| = \mathrm{Re}(z\overline{w})$. But because $|zw| = |z\overline{w}|$, so $z\overline{w}$ must be a nonnegative real number. Hence, $\arg(z) = \arg(w)$, and we conclude $z = sw$ for some $s > 0$.